# Perdi meu script da para recuperar?

Tags: mysql

Após uma tela azul, perdi meu trabalho no workbench, mas mantem o schema. Tem como recuperar ou terei de fazer novamente o trabalho?

Answer (score 2):

O `Workbench` assim como o `Office` faz um `auto save`. Se você usar versão 6.3 que é a mais atual, vá até `C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history` e você vai encontrar os `scripts` que você escreveu (salvos por você ou não) e os arquivos costumam estar salvos por data. Você pode abrir esses arquivos com um editor e decodificar os `HTML entities`. É meio trabalhoso mas você não perde o que já fez.